# Jbutton issue with text file and databse issue

Tags: java, mysql

I've the following code which i'm trying to make work . I have to read the content of a text file , which contains questions and save it to the database testsystem .

The main problem that i'm facing is that it's not inserted in the database. and i'm not sure whether it is reading the textfile or not.

I have received help from GameDroids , from what he explained above , i managed to get this , but now it's not only inserting and my upload button has become unresponsive , it doesn't trigger any event now. please i really need help.
any help will be glady appreciated .

For example for the bellow question, i shall have in my Category_questions : Collections, and for my questions : Which of these is not an example of a "real-life" collection? and for my quest_opt_a : a. The cards you hold in a card game. etc and for correct_option_answer i shall have d inserted in the database table.

this is the question :

Collections Which of these is not an example of a "real-life" collection? 
a. The cards you hold in a card game. 
b. Your favorite songs stored in your computer. 
c. The players on a soccer team. 
d. The number of pages in a book.

d.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
{
    String file = fileField.getText();

    SetGetQuestionFileName setGet = new SetGetQuestionFileName(file);


    try
    {    
        ConnectToDatabase database = new ConnectToDatabase();

                             // prepare the query
String query = "INSERT INTO questionnaire (category_questions, questions, quest_opt_a,quest_opt_b, quest_opt_c,  quest_opt_d, correct_option_answer ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 

                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = null;
                                    database.getConnection();   
                        preparedStmt = database.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

        if(ev.getActionCommand().equals("UPLOAD"))
        {
             // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File field can't be empty. Try again","ERROR",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);  

            File filePathString = new File(file);

                // load the file
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

                 //fis = new FileInputStream(filePathString);

                if(file.length() == 0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File field can't be empty. Try again","ERROR",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }

                else
                {
                    if(filePathString.exists() && filePathString.isFile())
                    {


                // read the file line by line
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
                    {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();

             String[] questionAnswer = line.split("?");//[ // line.split["?"] will split the line into two strings, right at the ? and put those two strings into an array. 
            String question = questionAnswer[0];  // so [0] will access the first element in that array - the question 
             String[] answers = questionAnswer[1].split(","); // now we split the string after the ? into many strings divided by comma


                        // create the mysql insert preparedstatement

         preparedStmt.setString(1, "JDBC");   
         preparedStmt.setString(2, question);  
         preparedStmt.setString(3, answers[0]);     
         preparedStmt.setString(4, answers[1]);      
         preparedStmt.setString(5, answers[2]);       
            preparedStmt.setString(6, answers[3]);      
         preparedStmt.setString(7, answers[4]);      

             preparedStmt.executeUpdate();


                        }

            //  database.disconnect();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File successfuly uploaded","INFORMATION",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            fileField.setText("");
                }               

        }

        if(!filePathString.exists() && !filePathString.isFile())

                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File coudn't be found. Do check file name.","ERROR",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }


}

catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

    if(ev.getActionCommand().equals("LOGOUT"))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you format your code properly? That's just unreadable ... I also don't understand your question

Comment: i've edited and brought up light to the questions

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your `JPanel` or `JFrame` or any other view class with `ActionListener` if you want, but it is generally a good idea to create a separate class for the `ActionListener`.

```
public class MyActionListener extends ActionListener{

   String myVariable;

   public MyActionListner(String variableINeedForTheAction){    // pass the parameters you need in the constructor or getter method
      this.myVariable = variableINeedForTheAction;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         this.myVariable = "actionPerformed";     // then, when the action gets performed you can access that variable
   }
}


public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
   //some code
   JButton myButton = new JButton();
   String text = "";
   MyActionListner buttonListener = new MyActionListener(text);   // instantiate your own action listener class and pass the variables you need for performing the action
   myButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);       // add the listener to some button
}
```

All this is done to separate your view from the controllers in your program. Imagine you have another button somewhere in another frame or panel and you want it to do the same thing as this button, then you can simply register another instance of your action listener, without having to copy the whole code.

Anyway, my guess is that you are doing too much work in your performed action and that the complete GUI becomes unresponsive because you are reading a file from disc and putting its content into a database in your actionPerformed method.

What you *could* try is using a Thread to handle all your upload / read / write stuff:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is running");

            File filePathString = new File(file);
            // load the file
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            //... do the reading and writing here

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is finished"); 
        }
    }, "Upload Thread");
    myThread.start();
}
```

Comment: good luck! Don't get confused with any values you might need in your ActionListener. If for example you want show some message in a `JLabel` when the transfer is done, just pass the complete `JLabel` variable to your ActionListener (e.g. in the constructor) – you will be able to set the text there.

Answer (score 0):

In fact as many people have suggested, the thread and swing workers where things which i really needed.

so i ended up with something like this :

```
try 
                    {

                Runnable r = new Runnable() 
                  {
                     @Override
                     public void run()
                     {


                        doWork();

                     }
                  };
     new Thread(r).start();

        }

        /*      catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }*/ 

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.getCause();
            }
```